# I have a trouble when use scrapy to write item to csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, byte

I try to write to csv file in Scrapy using CsvItemExporter.
The codes are here:

```
 class StockPipelineCSV(object):

 def open_spider(self,spider):
     self.file = open('stocks_01.csv', 'w')
     self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
     self.exporter.start_exporting()

 def close_spider(self,spider):
     self.exporter.finish_exporting()
     self.file.close()

 def process_item(self, item, spider):
     self.exporter.export_item(item)
     return item
```

When I run the project.I meet the error:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

So I go to exporters.py in scrapy and see the export_item() method.The codes are below:

```
#exporters.py  
def export_item(self, item):
    if self._headers_not_written:
        self._headers_not_written = False
        self._write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(item)

    fields = self._get_serialized_fields(item, default_value='',
                                         include_empty=True)
    values = list(self._build_row(x for _, x in fields))
    self.csv_writer.writerow(values)

def _build_row(self, values):
    for s in values:
        try:
            yield to_native_str(s, self.encoding)
        except TypeError:
            yield s
```

and the to_native_str(s, self.encoding) method is in python.py:

```
 #python.py
 def to_native_str(text, encoding=None, errors='strict'):
 """ Return str representation of `text`
 (bytes in Python 2.x and unicode in Python 3.x). """
     if six.PY2:
         return to_bytes(text, encoding, errors)
     else:
         return to_unicode(text, encoding, errors)
```

So I think the item has already converts to byte.But why error?
I search the error and get some solutions:use w+b mode to open the file,but the file's contents are messy words.
After that I try to write a test code to write to csv file:

```
# coding: utf-8

import csv

csvfile = open('D://t.csv', 'w+b')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow([str.encode('列1'), str.encode('列2'), str.encode('列3')])

data = [
    str.encode('值1'), str.encode('值2'), str.encode('值3')
]
writer.writerow(data)

csvfile.close()
```

I run it but get error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

But I think I have already converts the str to byte by str.encode().

I am very confused about str and the bytes-like object.I know byte is ascii code and str is unicode.But I don't understand why I get such errors.